# Problem on the limit of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Assertion: If $\{\alpha_k\}$ is a positive sequence satisfying $\sum \alpha_k =1$, there exists a positive sequence $\{\beta_k\}$ satisfying $\frac{\alpha_k}{\beta_k}\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow 0$ and $\sum \beta_k=1$.

I cannot show the above assertion.
I want to know how to construct a sequence $\{\beta_k\}$ with the above propeties.

Can someone please help me?
I am stuck. thank you.

Remarks:

$1$. The sequences are infinite.

$2$. Please note that $\alpha_k>0$ and $\beta_k>0$ for all $k=1,2,3,...$.

Comment: Is the sequence of finite length?

Comment: The sequences are infinite.

Comment: Hint: Let $\alpha_{k_j}<\frac  1 {j2^{j}}$, $\beta_{k_j}=j\alpha_{k_j}, \beta_k=0$ if $k >k_1$ and $k$ not of the type $k_j$.

Comment: Can't you just define $\{\beta_k\}$ to be $\{\alpha_k\}^2$ for $k>1$ , then add whatever number is necessary to the $\{\beta_1\}$ first term to ensure it still has a sum of 1?

Comment: @AmoebaProteus - you have to go the other way - since $\sum \alpha_k$ is finite, $\alpha_k \to 0$, so if $\beta_k = \alpha_k^2$, then $\frac {\alpha_k}{\beta_k} = \frac 1{\alpha_k} \to \infty$. The basic idea is good, but that isn't the right implementation.

Comment: Please note that $\alpha_k>0$ and $\beta_k>0$ for all $k=1,2,3,...$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\beta_{k}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}\alpha_{i}}-\sqrt{\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}\alpha_{i}},$$then it is clearly that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\beta_{k}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_{k}}=1$$and$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\alpha_{n}}{\beta_{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\alpha_{n}(\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=n}^{\infty}\alpha_{i}}+\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{\infty}\alpha_{i}})}{\alpha_{n}}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Just pick a sequence going to zero, and set $\frac{\alpha_k}{\beta_k}$ equal to it. For instance, if we pick the sequence $\frac 1 k$, that gives $\beta_k = k\alpha_k$.

What about the possibility (i.e. certainty) that this gives $\sum \beta_k>1$? Consider $f(n)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\beta_k$. This is a decreasing function of $n$ (the higher $n$ is, the more terms we drop). So all you need to do is prove that there is some $n$ such that $f(n)<1$. Then fill all the terms of $\{\beta_k\}$ before $n$ with values such that the total sum $\sum \beta$ is equal to $1$. This won't affect the limit of $\frac{\alpha_k}{\beta_k}$, as that doesn't care about any finite subset of terms.